# how to debug python fabric using pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, fabric

There are some posts on SO and tell me to use fab-script.py as startup script for pycharm. It's exactly what I used before. Now when I upgrade fabric to latest version, fab-script disappeared, and only fab.exe left there. I tried a lot of  other ways, but still failed to launch debugger in pycharm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final solution is to add line below at fabfile.py:

```
import fabric.main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fabric.main.main()
```

then you can debug the fabfile.py as a normal python script in pycharm.

---

For **Fabric 2** users this should work *(tested on Fabric `2.6.0`)*:

```py
import fabric.main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fabric.main.program.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

**How to run/debug Fabric (Fab) command in Pycharm**

1. run `which fab` from your virtualenv and take the output path
2. create new `run/debug configuration` with type = `python` script
3. configure it

   - script path = `output` from p.1
   - parameters =  *
   - working directory =

Example

- script path: /home/xxx/.virtualenvs/some/bin/fab
- parameters: local-restore-db --dump argument

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this setup on Windows, but on Linux/Mac, it's fairly straightforward:

1. Create a new Run Configuration in PyCharm for a Python script (when you click the "+" button, select the one labelled "Python")
2. The "Configuration" tab should be open.
3. For the "Script" field, enter the full path to `fab.exe`, like `C:\Python27\.....\fab.exe` or whatever it is.
4. For Script parameters, just try `-l`, to list the available commands. You'll tweak this later, and fill it in with whatever tasks you'd run from the command line, like "fab   **etc...**"
5. For the "Working directory" field, you'll want to set that to the directory that contains your fabfile.

And it's about as easy as that, at least on *nix. Sorry that I don't have a Windows setup, but do let us know if you do have any issues with the setup described above.

Comment: Pycharm actually runs the command below to start debug <<<< C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 52068 --file C:/Python27/Scripts/fab.exe -l >>>>>, but it failed with msessage "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\x90' in file C:/Python27/Scripts/fab.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared;"

Comment: How about just using `fab` on the command line, are you able to just run `fab -l`?

Comment: on command line, the actual command line is <<<<< "c:\python27\python.exe"  "C:\Python27\Scripts\fab.exe" -l >>>>

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a system where I can attempt to replicate this, so I'm out of ideas. Seems really weird though. Just had a random thought: don't rule out the possibility of bugs in the PyCharm helper file, `pydev.py` - I had a crazy issue with debugging a while back, and it turned out that there was a bug in that file, and I had to copy a version from a previous installation into place. I'm not saying that is the problem here - but keep an open mind! Sorry I can't help more, good luck though!

Comment: Good to know the story about the pydev issue. Thanks a lot!